# How to check user role in a resource server when using Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api, thinktecture-ident-server

I download `[Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3][1]` and the corresponding clients projects. I want to check the user role in the `SampleAspNetWebApi` project.
 So i change the sample method as follows

```
 [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]

 public class IdentityController : ApiController
    {
        public dynamic Get()
        {
            var principal = User as ClaimsPrincipal;

            return from c in principal.Identities.First().Claims
                   select new 
                   {
                       c.Type,
                       c.Value
                   };
        }
    }
```

I use the `WPF hybrid client` to  Call the service and use `alice` user that has the `Admin` role.
But it returns UnAuthorized error.
The user is authenticated but the role is not set.

How can i check the user role in  SampleAspNetWebApi project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Authorize attribute looks for a Microsoft/.NET specific role claim type

http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role

We emit a simple 'role' claim.

You can map the incoming claims to what ASP.NET expects - but this is turned off - try removing this line from startup.cs:`

`JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = ClaimMappings.None;`

Comment: Are the roles available in webapi project to map?
why are the roles  returned in id_token while access_token is sent to webapi project?

Comment: That depends on your scope configuration. Check the wiki for documentation.

Comment: As @leastprivilege said, that depends on the scope configuration. I added idmgr(which is a resource type scope and has role ScopeClaim) to my scope and then it worked without any claim mapping. Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem, but with IdentityManager (not IdentityServer)... How would I map the claims in this case?